# Procedure or function XXX has too many arguments specified

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

So I have been battling this problem all day now. At first I thought it must be with my calling code even though that all looked good. The calling code is just a standard call from a VB codebehind file and is not linked to data binding in anyway. I mention this as I have seen a lot of other people with this problem have had it due to DataGrids etc.

I then went to the database itself and manually executed the procedure and it gave the same error in SQL Sevrer Manager. I have tried deleting the procedure and re-creating it even down to the point of re-writing it from scratch and it still happens. I also tried removing the default NULL value from the @Password parameter but still no change.

I am running SQL Server 2008 R2

Here is the procedure code:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_AddUser] 
    @Username       varchar(50),
    @Fullname       varchar(50),
    @Password       varchar(50) = NULL,
    @Datecreated    DateTime,
    @RoleID         int,
    @ResetPwd       bit,
    @Email          varchar(50), 
    @locked         bit, 
    @Sign           varchar(max), 
    @Sysuser        bit
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO users ( 
        user_name,
        full_name,
        password,
        datetime_created,
        role_id,
        password_reset,
        email_address, 
        locked, 
        email_signature, 
        asrsys_user)
    VALUES (
        @Username,
        @Fullname,
        @Password,
        @Datecreated,
        @RoleID,
        @ResetPwd,
        @Email, 
        @locked, 
        @Sign, 
        @Sysuser)
END
```

Comment: Where's your code for manually executing this procedure that you said also gives the same error?

Comment: can you paste the schema of users?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Sorry by that I meant using `Execute Stored Procedure` from the context menu in SQL Server Management Studio

Comment: Also, you should avoid using `sp_` as a prefix for your stored procedures - it's reserved for Microsoft use - and invokes weird lookup rules (`master` is searched before the current database) that would mean that, were MS to introduce an SP of the same name (via e.g. a service pack), the MS SP would "win".

Comment: The problem is in the name - [sp_adduser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181422%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) is built-in stored procedure. It is being called instead of your procedure. Just change the name.

Comment: Let's see the actual call you made to the to the stored proc in SQL Management studio.  My suspicion is that there's a mis-formed argument that majkes it look like two arguments.  Have you tried calling the arguments out by parameter name?  `Exec sp_AddUser @Username='bob', @Fullname='Robert Plant',  etc/ ` ????

Comment: And the prefix `sp_` does NOT mean `Stored procedure`.  It means `System Procedure` and just allows the procedure, if placed in Master database, to be used from any database on the server without specifying master in the call.  It should not be used for stored procedures in your application databases.  SInce there is already a stored proc in master (from Microsoft) that is named sp_AddUser, your call is executing that not the one you wrote.  Change the name of yours to just AddUser and it will be fine

Comment: Good catch @NikolaMarkovinović, you should make it the answer so we can give you the rep points

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should avoid using `sp_` as a prefix for your stored procedures - it's reserved for Microsoft use - and invokes weird lookup rules (`master` is searched before the current database) that would mean that, were MS to introduce an SP of the same name (via e.g. a service pack), the MS SP would "win".

But in this case, Microsoft have *already* "won" - they have a stored procedure called `sp_adduser`, and it's that one that's being invoked. Rename your stored proc.

Comment: Yup after your comment I decided to try it on the chance it might be related and it is as you say the issue. 3 hours on a naming issue. Lesson learnt. Thanks for the note regarding sp_ being reserved though. Something I had never picked up before.

Comment: @Zammalad: I'd go so far as to say using the same prefix on all of your stored procedures is a bad idea.  It's completely unnecessary as they are already organized in the "stored procedures" area of management studio and all you are really doing is making it harder to quickly locate it in the list.  For this type of thing I'd probably have named it "UserAdd" that way the procs are grouped by the tables they are operating on.

Comment: @Zammalad - as Chris points out, it's unnecessary to use prefixes and the like in SQL Server. Not only are they organised separately in the visual tools, but the syntax of SQL makes the object type unambiguous in any particular situation (except for between tables and views, which shouldn't be distinguished between anyway). E.g. if you see `exec X @abc,@def`, can you guess the type of object that `X` is without looking it up?

Comment: Indeed, I have just gone through and update all the naming to be better eg User_X, Customer_X and so on, so that the procedures are grouped together by what they relate to eg User_Add, User_Edit, User_Remove etc